# Slow Input Writing on User Form

Tags: excel, forms, vba, combobox, userform

I have a user form which occurs in only first opening of the workbook to get Project Information from user.

The form is very basic, I have 12 labels and each label has either 1 TextBox, 1 ComboBox or maximum 1 TextBox and 1 ComboBox together.

The problem is when this User Form pops-up, **the input speed is extra slow**. And as long as there isn't any major codes within this form it shouldn't take that much time. Even there isn't any automatic calculation in the page that where I reflect the inputs as the outputs.(That's why this question doesn't help me: [How to improve the saving speed for userform in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948081/how-to-improve-the-saving-speed-for-userform-in-excel-vba))

(P.S: ComboBoxes' row source are named ranges, but I have another forms with same style and I don't face with this problem)

Here are my output codes:

```
'Project Name Input
Private Sub TextBox7_Change()
Sheet2.Range("E3").Value = TextBox7.Value
End Sub

'Customer Name input
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("E4").Value = TextBox1.Value
End Sub

'Region Input
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("E5").Value = ComboBox1.Value
End Sub

'City Input
Private Sub TextBox6_Change()
Sheet2.Range("G5").Value = TextBox6.Value
End Sub

'Bid Currency Input
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("E6").Value = ComboBox2.Value
End Sub

'Industry Type Input
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
Sheet2.Range("E7").Value = ComboBox3.Value
End Sub

'Application Type Input
Private Sub ComboBox4_Change()
Sheet2.Range("E8").Value = ComboBox4.Value
End Sub

'Opportunity/Job Number Input
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()
Sheet2.Range("E9").Value = TextBox5.Value
End Sub

'Plant Capacity First Input
Private Sub TextBox4_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("E10").Value = TextBox4.Value
End Sub

'Plant Capacity Second (Unit) Input
Private Sub ComboBox5_Change()
Sheet2.Range("F10").Value = ComboBox5.Value
End Sub

'Number of Trains First Input (each)
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("E11").Value = TextBox2.Value
End Sub

'Number of Trains Second Input (percentage)
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
 Sheet2.Range("g11").Value = TextBox3.Value
End Sub

'Process Type 1st Input
Private Sub ComboBox6_Change()
Sheet2.Range("E12").Value = ComboBox6.Value
End Sub

'Process Type 2nd Input
Private Sub ComboBox10_Change()
Sheet2.Range("f12").Value = ComboBox10.Value
End Sub

'Process Type 3rd Input
Private Sub ComboBox9_Change()
Sheet2.Range("g12").Value = ComboBox9.Value
End Sub

'Process Type 4th Input
Private Sub ComboBox8_Change()
Sheet2.Range("H12").Value = ComboBox8.Value
End Sub

'Engineering Specifications Input
Private Sub ComboBox7_Change()
Sheet2.Range("e13").Value = ComboBox7.Value
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

So, to make it more clear, as an example: As the first input is Project Name, when I start to type Project name, After I press each word, there is almost a second lag to continue to write and that's definitely not normal.

Comment: You have it set up so that, every time the TextBox is changed (i.e. the user types a character), the code is writing the value to the workbook (and the workbook will recalculate anything dependent on that cell) - that will be slow.  You should only update the workbook once the user is finished typing.

Comment: I aimed to only update the workbook at the last row, which is Userform_Click ==> Unload Me. But hmmmm if It doesn't work, So should I bring all the codes inside one private sub?

Comment: Unless you **need** to store all the information as each field is entered (in which case I would at least change to a `TextBox1_Exit` event instead of `TextBox1_Change`) then, yes, I would write the contents of all the TextBoxes and ComboBoxes to the worksheet when the user clicks an "OK" button of some sort.  (I wouldn't use the form's `Click` event - it is too easy for a user to **accidentally** click somewhere on the form and therefore close the form before they were ready.)

Comment: Then what should be the name of my Private Sub? 
I tried to put all of this ComboBox.Value and TextBox.Value actions into one sub like Private Sub InputUserForm() , the speed becomes normal, but when I close the form, **the outputs don't come through worksheet** in this case. What do I miss again? (I know it's very basic issue from now on but I'm just stucked.)

Comment: Create a button - by default it will be called `CommandButton1` - change the button's `Caption` to say "OK" (or something similar) - then put your code into the sub called `CommandButton1_Click`.  (Or give the button a new, non-default `Name`, e.g. "OKButton", and use `OKButton_Click`.)  Then, when the user clicks the button, your code will run.

Comment: Ah, yeap, now I know the direction now, I was planning to put that CommandButton after everything and that's why I was missing the main point.Thanks YowE3K, but this is now an answer, please post it for me to approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is currently set up so that, every time the TextBox is changed (i.e. the user types a character), the code is writing the value to the workbook (and the workbook will recalculate anything dependent on that cell). That will be slow.

Unless you need to store all the information as each field is entered (in which case I would at least change to a `TextBox1_Exit` event instead of `TextBox1_Change`) then I would suggest you write the contents of all the TextBoxes and ComboBoxes to the worksheet when the user clicks an "OK" button of some sort.

(I wouldn't use the form's Click event - it is too easy for a user to accidentally click somewhere on the form and therefore close the form before they were ready.)

I suggest you:

- Create a button - by default it will be called CommandButton1, but you can change its `Name` to something like "OKButton" if you like.
- Change the button's `Caption` to say "OK", or something similar, so that the user knows to click it when they have entered all their information.
- Put your code into the sub called `CommandButton1_Click` (or `OKButton_Click` if you renamed the button to `OKButton`).

Then, when the user clicks the button, your code will run.

Possible code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()        
    'Project Name Input
    Sheet2.Range("E3").Value = TextBox7.Value
    'Customer Name input
    Sheet2.Range("E4").Value = TextBox1.Value
    'Region Input
    Sheet2.Range("E5").Value = ComboBox1.Value
    'City Input
    Sheet2.Range("G5").Value = TextBox6.Value
    'Bid Currency Input
    Sheet2.Range("E6").Value = ComboBox2.Value
    'Industry Type Input
    Sheet2.Range("E7").Value = ComboBox3.Value
    'Application Type Input
    Sheet2.Range("E8").Value = ComboBox4.Value
    'Opportunity/Job Number Input
    Sheet2.Range("E9").Value = TextBox5.Value
    'Plant Capacity First Input
    Sheet2.Range("E10").Value = TextBox4.Value
    'Plant Capacity Second (Unit) Input
    Sheet2.Range("F10").Value = ComboBox5.Value
    'Number of Trains First Input (each)
     Sheet2.Range("E11").Value = TextBox2.Value
    'Number of Trains Second Input (percentage)
    Sheet2.Range("g11").Value = TextBox3.Value
    'Process Type 1st Input
    Sheet2.Range("E12").Value = ComboBox6.Value
    'Process Type 2nd Input
    Sheet2.Range("f12").Value = ComboBox10.Value
    'Process Type 3rd Input
    Sheet2.Range("g12").Value = ComboBox9.Value
    'Process Type 4th Input
    Sheet2.Range("H12").Value = ComboBox8.Value
    'Engineering Specifications Input
    Sheet2.Range("e13").Value = ComboBox7.Value
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: YowE3K, I've just tried this code, for the input writing yes, everything is working normally, but when I click the CommandButton1, it takes a bit long to run this code. What would be the reason, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Mertinc - Hard to tell - perhaps you have a lot of calculations on the sheet you are writing to?  (If so, set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start of the sub and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` at the end so that it only calculates once.)  Or perhaps you have some `Worksheet_Change` events (or other events) on the sheet?